# Is there a way to add some tabs inside Composite C1 function?

Tags: c#, function, content-management-system, c1-cms

I'm using the 6th version of Composite c1 CMS. And i'm wondering about is there a way to add some kind of tabs inside Composite functions? For example, i have a function

```
`public override string MyFunction
{
    get { return "SomeFunction"; }
}

[FunctionParameter(DefaultValue = "Nad")]
public string Name { get; set; }

[FunctionParameter(Label = "Another Field", DefaultValue = "", HideInSimpleView = true)]
public string AnotherField { get; set; }

[FunctionParameter(Label = "Some URL", DefaultValue = "", HideInSimpleView = true)]
public string Url { get; set; }`
```

and i want to add some kind of tabs, that user should interact with only if, for example, function name is "someName". Is there a way to a)add that kind of tabs,so user could switch between the main tab and the other one; and b)conditionally show this tabs?

Answer (score 1):

No, unlike data forms, where the layout can be defined with an xml file, such functionality isn't implemented for function calls, when one only can define widgets for function parameters but not the overall layout.

It is possible to replace the default function call editor with a custom page, like it is done in the FormBuilder package.

http://docs.c1.orckestra.com/Console/Custom-Function-Call-Editor

The available example is based on WebForms, so it may not be straightforward to implement.

http://docs.c1.orckestra.com/Console/Custom-Function-Call-Editor/Web-Form

Comment: Thank you, i'm using exactly the same technology (webforms)